# Set 100% width of tr

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following table:

[image: Table]

I would want the rows starting from the second column to fill the three following columns. In other words, the year column has to fill 25% of the table (the same as "Anio"), and the other two rows inside the year row, has to fill 75% of the table (the second, third and fourth columns (25% each one)), and the other two inside "OSDE" have to fill 50% of the table (the third and fourth columns).

I have this (I am building it in js):

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="25%">Anio</th>
    <th width="25%">Obra social</th>
    <th width="25%">Doctor</th>
    <th width="25%">Valor</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="2">2018</td>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" rowspan="2">OSDE</td>
      <td>medico1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>medico2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" rowspan="2">UP</td>
      <td>medico1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>medico2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="2">2019</td>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" rowspan="2">OSDE</td>
      <td>medico1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>medico2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" rowspan="2">UP</td>
      <td>medico1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>medico2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main problems in your code:

1.) The cells containing  the years need `rowspan="4"` (they go across 4 lines)

2.) You *must not* nest a `tr` within a `tr` (you can only nest complete tables consisting of `table`, `tr`s and `td`s, and only inside `td`s). Just be careful to create complete rows where the number of `td`s is identical in all rows, also considering the `rowspan` settings of all cells in previous rows.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="25%">Anio</th>
    <th width="25%">Obra social</th>
    <th width="25%">Doctor</th>
    <th width="25%">Valor</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="4">2018</td>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="2">OSDE</td>
    <td>medico1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>medico2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="2">UP</td>
    <td>medico1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>medico2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="4">2019</td>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="2">OSDE</td>
    <td>medico1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>medico2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" rowspan="2">UP</td>
    <td>medico1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>medico2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```